# Cannot import modules even with 'esModuleInterop' set I get "This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used [...]"

Tags: node.js, typescript, import

I am using WebStorm and have the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "module": "esnext",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es2017",
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
   ],
  "lib": [
   "es2017",
   "dom"
  ]
 },
 "files": [
  "/Users/ich/WebstormProjects/BridgeScript/HopBridgeScript.ts"
 ],
}
```

When I now try to run my code with `tsc HopBridgeScript.ts&& node HopBridgeScript.js` I get

```
ich@Dominiks-MBP BridgeScript % tsc HopBridgeScript.ts&& node HopBridgeScript.js
node_modules/@hop-protocol/sdk/dist/src/watchers/BaseWatcher.d.ts:2:8 - error TS1259: Module '"/Users/ich/WebstormProjects/BridgeScript/node_modules/eventemitter3/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

2 import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3';
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/eventemitter3/index.d.ts:134:1
    134 export = EventEmitter;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.


Found 1 error.
```

This is the beginning of the code:

```
import { providers, Wallet, BigNumber } from "ethers";
import { Hop, Chain } from "@hop-protocol/sdk";
import { formatUnits } from "ethers/lib/utils";
import { getEthPriceNow } from "get-eth-price";

...
```

Comment: Change `import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3'` to `import * as EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3'` OR change the `esModuleInterop` flag in `tsconfig.json` to `false`

Comment: When I change `esModuleInterop` to `false` there is no change. Maybe my `tsconfig.json` is not even used when I start and compile with `tsc HopBridgeScript.ts&& node HopBridgeScript.js`?

And I do not import `EventEmitter` explicitly. Should I add `import * as EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3'`?

Comment: try it yes. I do not know the detailed background, but `esmoduleINterop` flag basically changes between `*` and `default` import styles.

Comment: No that doesn't work, unfortunately. Still get the same error when I change the import style.